# Java PipedInputStream thread is in BLOCKED state with no other thread holding the lock?

Tags: java, multithreading, io, inputstream, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm using **apache http client** to execute some post requests to a target server, writing the content using piped streams. So, basically, from one thread http client is reading from `PipedInputStream` and from another thread I'm writing the content on a `PipedOutputStream`.

Every once in a while I'm getting thread dumps and seeing lots of threads blocked on `java.io.PipedInputStream.read()` method executing `wait(1000)` line. The **BLOCKED** state means that the reading thread is waiting to acquire back the lock after `1000 ms` elapsed. But what I don't understand is why I can't see any writing thread to hold the lock in the thread dump. What am I missing and how can I avoid having threads blocked?

Here are some lines from within thread dump file:

```
Thread 7912: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.io.PipedInputStream.read() @bci=142, line=326 (Compiled frame)
 - java.io.PipedInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) @bci=43, line=377 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.http.entity.InputStreamEntity.writeTo(java.io.OutputStream) @bci=75, line=140 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RequestEntityProxy.writeTo(java.io.OutputStream) @bci=10, line=123 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(org.apache.http.HttpEntityEnclosingRequest) @bci=31, line=156 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.sendRequestEntity(org.apache.http.HttpEntityEnclosingRequest) @bci=5, line=162 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(org.apache.http.HttpRequest, org.apache.http.HttpClientConnection, org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext) @bci=223, line=238 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(org.apache.http.HttpRequest, org.apache.http.HttpClientConnection, org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext) @bci=25, line=123 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(org.apache.http.conn.routing.HttpRoute, org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestWrapper, org.apache.http.client.protocol.HttpClientContext,     org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpExecutionAware) @bci=714, line=271 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(org.apache.http.conn.routing.HttpRoute, org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestWrapper, org.apache.http.client.protocol.HttpClientContext,    org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpExecutionAware) @bci=447, line=184 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(org.apache.http.conn.routing.HttpRoute, org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestWrapper, org.apache.http.client.protocol.HttpClientContext,    org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpExecutionAware) @bci=39, line=88 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(org.apache.http.HttpHost, org.apache.http.HttpRequest, org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext) @bci=168, line=184 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest, org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext) @bci=14, line=82 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest) @bci=6, line=107 (Compiled frame)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `read()` on a `PipedInputStream` and the buffer is empty, it will block in `wait()` on some object until the corresponding `PipedOutputStream` writes something and notifies whatever object the `PipedInputStream` is waiting on. This is just the familiar

```
synchronized (lock)
{
    while (...)
        lock.wait();
}
```

pattern, where `wait()` releases the lock for someone else to synchronize and notify on.

Why you're using piped streams at all is another mystery. They are only a toy.

Comment: If the buffer is empty, the state of the reading thread within thead dump will be `TIMED_WAITING` not `BLOCKED`. And btw, that wait from `PipedInputStream` has a timeout. Once that timeout expires, the reading thread is trying to get back the lock that was released executing the wait method, and if it cannot take it will be in `BLOCKED` state. If it succeeds it will be in `RUNNIGN` state. This is odd, because this means there should be another thread (the writing thread) holding that lock, but there is no trace of it in the thread dump.

Comment: I'm working on a proxy http server on top of `apache mina`. So this server is receiving a bunch of bytes, decodes them in an http object, and then constructs and executes another request to a target server. So within a thread I'm opening a stream to the target server using `apache httpclient` which wraps the `PipedInputStream` within the request, and from another thread I'm pumping the data using `PipedOutputStream`.

Comment: None of this explains why you're using piped streams in the first place. I used them exactly once, in 1997, and removed them almost immediately.

Comment: I'm using piped streams as I need to support big file uploads. I tried CircularByteBuffer from https://ostermiller.org/utils/src/CircularByteBuffer.java.html as an alternative to jdk pipe streams, but it is too slow as it is not using wait/notify for synchronization. Any idea about alternative to pipestreams?

Answer (score -1):

When you call read on InputStream it will wait until an OutputStream will eventually get the data. That's why you have waiting blokcs. So, it's not about writing and locking, it's about reading and waiting while inputStream will have data.

Comment: If there is no data, the reading thread will be in `RUNNABLE` or `TIMED_WAITING` state as it is either running the while loop within read method, or it is executing the wait(long) from within that loop. Being in `BLOCKED` state means other thread is having that lock, but there is no such writing thread in the thread dump.

Comment: Output streams don't 'get data', and it isn't 'about reading and waiting while inputStream will have data'. What with that and the mis-spellings, this answer is barely comprehensible, and wrong where it is comprehensible.